# Turn on/off Angular1 data-ng-click event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and JQuery. We are customizing a third party application which was developed in Angular1 and We don't have any access to their source code but, we can run our custom scripts on top it. Here, I have to enable or disable a click event on div tag based on some condition. The following is the source code.

```
<div class="uc-ok"
    data-ng-class="{'disabled': getButtonDisabled()}"
    data-ng-click="selectAndClose($event)"
    style="display: block;">OK</div>
```

I have tried the following approaches,

```
$('.uc-ok').addClass("disabled");// for disabling it

$('.uc-ok').removeClass("disabled");//for enabling it again
```

In this case the button appears to be disabled, but still click function is working on a disabled button.

I have tried,

```
$('.uc-ok').off("click");

$('.uc-ok').on("click");
```

In this case, the click function was completely off and not able to turn it on. when turn it on the actual `selectAndClose(event)` should be called.

Please help me with what I am missing here.

Comment: `$.fn.off` only removes events bound to an element with jQuery.  Angular, as far as I am aware, does not bind event to elements with jQuery.  You could try `$('.uc-ok').prop('disabled', true)` to actually disable the button, rather than putting a class on it of 'disabled'

Comment: Thank you for quick response @Taplar. I have tried that one as well. But, it is not affecting at all, the prop() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily there is a simple CSS option for disabling interaction with HTML elements. You can use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property to disable mouse events on an element.

So the simplest thing would be to just add this to your `.disabled` class style:

```
/*css*/
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and it will no longer receive mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to affect anything with angular, after you modify the element, you need to recompile it against the element's scope.

```
function removeClickHandler()//call this to remove the click handler
{
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("uc-ok")[0];//button object
    button.removeAttribute("data-ng-click");
    angularCompile(button);
}

function addClickHandler()//call this to add it back in
{
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("uc-ok")[0];//button object
    button.setAttribute("data-ng-click", "selectAndClose($event)");
    angularCompile(button);
}    

function angularCompile(node)//only works if app uses ng-app attribute
{
    angular.element("[ng-app]").injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element(node).scope();
        $compile(node)(scope);
    });     
}
```